# How to paint with the clone option in Texture Paint?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I would like to use the clone tool with texture paint, but as soon as I choose Texture Paint, the mesh is white, and I cannot paint on it.

I created a new UV Map, after I project the image from view, the image of reference appears well on the mesh in Object Mode, but I get this white color in Texture Paint Mode. I followed this tutorial : https://youtu.be/p4ngVoGIj1Q?t=15m56s but the version of Blender is not the same, so the settings are a bit different.

I tried to play with the clone settings, the options in the shader menu : GLSL/Multitexture, but nothing changes.

Would you know how to use this clone effect in Blender 2.72b ?

---

EDIT #4: it is confusing, sorry. Here is a new example : the clone painting works. But when I click on the paintTo UV Map, which is the image I should export at the end, the painting does not correctly match the seams :

This is when I paint :

[image]

This is when I click on the uv map : it is not the same result as the previous painting :

[image]

Here are the files :

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35661

http://www.pasteall.org/pic/86965

Comment: Showing the results that you are getting would be helpful.  Maybe you should upload a .blend to PasteAll.org and paste the link here.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Actually I tried again with a cube, I don't have the same result, but I still can't paint from the first uv map to the second. Could you please give me the steps with a simple cube and an image? Create a cube > Create 2 uv maps, 1 with project from view, the other with the seams > activate Texture Paint, add a new slot > then ... not sure how to  select one uv map, and how to continue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the render is set to Cycles you can add two textures to the material and they should both show up as slots in texture paint.  Be sure to add a UV Map node for each texture and set the appropriate UV Map.

Enter Texture Paint mode and activate "Clone From Paint Slot".

The texture that is being painted to should be selected in the section named "Available Paint Slots"

The texture that is being painted from should be selected in the section named "Source Clone Slot".

All the settings I used are shown in the following animation.

[image]

*Update* in response to a comment requesting more information.

Textures can be drag 'N dropped from the hard drive file system.  They can be added in as texture nodes by looking through the menu that is called up when the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> is used.  They can also be added by drag 'N dropping the image icon from the UV Image Editor.

[image]

Using Blender Render you can add images to the texture slots.  I think the limit is 18 slots per material for BI.  I'm not sure if the BI node editor has the same limit, probably not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I cannot add 2 textures to 1 material? So I added 2 materials. But it is maybe not the solution. Could you have a look to my blend file? http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35590 Sorry, I know it might be simple, but I am a bit stuck now.

Comment: Hi MarcCLintDion, I edited my first post, I could not do the same settings as in your gif. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Very nice, thanks (I also had to click on the "Material" icon, did not know about that ;) ) Thanks.

Comment: I have  a small issue, could you please have a look at it? I added images and the blend file, with explanations. :)

Comment: Let me know if you are still having trouble after looking at that.  I have not looked at your .blend file yet because the words you choose are ambiguous and I'm not sure what you would like to see.  It would be more clear if you said something like, "I would like the wood palette image painted onto the dog", (if that is what you want) :)

Comment: (I erased a comment so what I wrote above is a bit confusing, sorry).  I just looked at the .blend.  The images are not packed in so it would be helpful if you load them to PasteAll.org as well.  I'll see if I can set it up properly, explain what the issue is and then repost the repaired file for you.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate. I edited my post with a new blend file. I packed the images, but just in case, I added them to pasteall.org.

Comment: I was a bit confused before, now that you have changed the setup twice to be something different I am having more difficulty trying to understand your issue and what you want.  There is a way we can deal with the original problem easily enough.  You should download Blender 2.63 and following the video's steps as shown.  Practice until you are comfortable then take what you learned there and here and then start using the upgraded version of Blender.  Here is a link to the Blender release archives.  http://download.blender.org/release/ enjoy :)

Comment: OK I got it working :) Thanks for the support, I appreciate it. The difference with before was... I use Blender Render (maybe it is the same with cycles), I had to select the uv maps - in - the clone menu, and the clone painting goes to the right seams. So I can now change from one uv map to another, without the texture to change suddenly. If this can help others. Thanks again.