# Clone-brush paints with wrong color

Tags: 3d-view, texture-painting

Such a simple task and such unexpected behaviour from the *Clone-brush*. I want to pick up green color from the opposite side and place it on the red dot (doing it in 3D viewport).

What I get is **black instead of green**. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It paints with right color - according to how it works. Cloning with 3d Cursor works taking the viewport camera orientation into account. So if you oriented the view by 45 degrees between X and Y planes it would clone red dot to the blackness present there as skewed red dot (according to how it appears to be visible when cloning). Thus now it doesn't see red dot and clones black color. You can use Clone From Paint Slot as [in related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28424/how-to-paint-with-the-clone-option-in-texture-paint) but operating with 2 images (or not use clone).

Comment: This is how all similar tools are working (other 3d programms) or only Blender issue?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate workflow and a much more controlled one is to load your canvas image as a brush texture in the basic TexBrush and use stencil as mapping for the brush - then you can move the image and rotate it exactly how you want it to align, and paint that part into the image.

edit: The Clone brush is mainly meant for cloning pixels to hide the UV seams, and not exactly a way to copy sections of paint onto the canvas without also picking up areas you might not want to pick up - those extra parts usually mean more work to paint out.